# Dynamism in excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I work with +OFFSET('monthly-2020'!$B$1;MATCH('PGP2'!$C$11;'monthly-2020'!$B$2:$B$978248;0);**1**) formula. The last argument stands for the number of columns I want to move with regard to my reference cell. However, I need to move 10 columns, so each time I need to change the last argument of the cell. Does anyone know a way to make last argument of the cell change as you drag it across columns?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `1` with `COLUMNS($A:A)` which results in 1.
If you drag it to the right it will change to `COLUMNS($A:B)` which results in `2`, etc.

The `$` locks that column letter. The column letter without the `$` will change if you drag to a different column.